# RTK Query endpoints and RTK actions happening out of order

Tags: reactjs, redux-toolkit, rtk-query

I'm having this weird issue where my RTK Query requests are happening in a strange order.

We've got the RTK `sports` slice, and in the same file I've defined the `useLoadSports` hook

```
const sportsSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'sports', initialState: {},
  reducers: {
    setSports: (state, action) => action.payload,
  },
});

export const sports = sportsSlice.reducer;
export const { setSports } = sportsSlice.actions;

export const useLoadSports = () => {
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const { data: sports, ...result } = useGetSportsQuery();
  
  useEffect(() => { console.log('useLoadSports'); }, []);
  
  useEffect(() => {
    if (sports) {
      console.log('SETTING SPORTS');
      dispatch(setSports(sports));
    }
  }, [sports]);
  
  return result;
};
```

The `Application` component uses this hook as it loads some data needed throughout the app.

```
const useInitialLoad = () => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('useInitialLoad');
  }, []);
  
  const { isLoading: sportsLoading } = useLoadSports(); // below
  const ready = !sportsLoading;
  return { ready };
};

const Application: React.FC<Props> = () => {
  const { ready } = useInitialLoad();
  if (!ready) return <h1>Loading app data</h1>;
  
  return (
    <S.Wrapper>
      <AppRouter />
    </S.Wrapper>
  );
};
```

The `AppRouter` actually iterates over a config object to create `Route`s. I'm assuming that's not our issue here.

Anyway, then the `PlayerPropsPage` component calls `useGetPropsDashboardQuery`.

```
const PlayerPropsPage = () => {
  const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useGetPropsDashboardQuery();
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('LOADING PlayerPropsPage');
  }, [])
  
  return /* markup */
}
```

The query's `queryFn` uses the sports that were saved into the store by `useLoadSports`

```
export const { useGetPropsDashboardQuery, ...extendedApi } = adminApi.injectEndpoints({
  endpoints: build => ({
    getPropsDashboard: build.query<PropAdminUIDashBoard, void>({
      queryFn: async (_args, { getState }, _extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        console.log('PROPS ENDPOINT');
        
        const result = await baseQuery({ url });
        const dashboard = result.data as PropAdminDashBoard;
        const { sports } = getState() as RootState;
        
        if (!Object.entries(sports).length) {
          throw new Error('No sports found');
        }
        
        // use the sports, etc.
      },
    }),
  }),
});
```

I'd think it would use the `setSports` action before even rendering the router (and hence calling the props endpoint or loading the page, and I'd *really* think it would render the `PlayerPropsPage` before calling the props query, but here's the log:

```
useInitialLoad
useLoadSports
LOADING PlayerPropsPage
PROPS ENDPOINT
SETTING SPORTS
```

Another crazy thing is if I move the `getState()` call in the endpoint above the call to `baseQuery`, the sports haven't been stored yet, and the error is thrown.

Why is this happening this way?

Comment: Why do you need the sport in the second query ? you need to pass it to the back, or just to merge sport query + dashboard query once the dashboard query is finished ?

Comment: The dashboard query does not include the sport name but does include `sportId`, and I want to "bake in" the sport name before the data is returned, so the actual consumers of the data (components) can use the sport name as if it were there all along. I would use `transformResponse` except I need to get the sports from the store (to look up `sports[sportId].sportName`) so I need `getState` which is only available in `queryFn`

Comment: You can do the two queries then inside a selector creating your output object ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bunch of random observations:

- you should really not dispatch that `setSports` action in a useEffect here. If you really want to have a slice with the result of your `useGetSportsQuery`, then add an `extraReducers` for `api.endpoints.getSports.fulfilled`. See [this example](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/rtk-query/usage/examples#using-extrareducers):

```
// from the example
extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder.addMatcher(
      api.endpoints.login.matchFulfilled,
      (state, { payload }) => {
        state.token = payload.token
        state.user = payload.user
      }
    )
  },
```

- I don't see why you even copy that data into the state just to use a complicated `queryFn` instead of just passing it down as props, using a `query` and passing it in as `useGetPropsDashboardQuery(sports)`. That way that `getPropsDashboard` will update if the `sports` argument changes - which will never happen if you take the extra logic with the `getState()` and all the other magic.
- you could even simplify this further:

```js
const { data: sports } = useGetSportsQuery()
const result = useGetPropsDashboardQuery( sports ? sports : skipToken )
```

No need for a slice, no need to have that logic spread over multiple components, no need for a queryFn. queryFn is an escape hatch and it really doesn't seem like you need it.

Comment: These are interesting ideas. The reason I'm loading the `sports` into the store is because other components we build in the future will definitely need it as well. Although I hadn't thought about the fact that I could just call the sports query hook again since it caches. (Also, `sports` should never change, it's just "static" data, that's why it's part of the initial load). I'll rethink, rework, and report back!

Comment: I've decided to mark this as the answer. I went the route of taking the sports out of the traditional redux store entirely, calling the sports query and then passing them directly to the props dashboard query. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The current behaviour is normal even if it's not what you expect.

- you have a main hook who do a query
- the first query start
- when the query is finish it does "rerender" and does this

  - dispatch the result of the sports
  - the second query start

So there is no guarantee that you have sports in the store when you start the second query. As all is done with hooks (you can technically do it with hooks but that's another topic)

## How to wait a thunk result to trigger another one ?

You have multiple ways to do it. It depends also if you need to wait thoses two queries or not.

### [Listener middleware](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createListenerMiddleware)

If you want to run some logic when a thunk is finish, having a listener can help you.

```js
listenerMiddleware.startListening({
  matcher: sportsApi.endpoints.getSports.fulfilled,
  effect: async (action, listenerApi) => {         
    listenerApi.dispatch(dashboardApi.endpoints.getPropsDashboard.initiate())
   }
  },
})
```

In addition, instead of setting sports in the store with a `dispatch` inside the `useEffect`. You can plug your query into the [extraReducers](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createSlice#extrareducers). here is an example:

```js
createSlice({
  name: 'sports',
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) => {
    builder
      .addMatcher(
        sportsApi.endpoints.getSports.fulfilled,
        (state, action) => {
          state.sports = action.payload.sports
        }
      )
  },
})
```

### Injecting thunk arguments with a selector

If you use directly pass sports as a variable to the query when they change they'll re-trigger the query. here is an example:

```
const PlayerPropsPage = () => {
  const { data: sports, ...result } = useGetSportsQuery();
  const { data, isLoading, isError, error } = useGetPropsDashboardQuery(sports);
}
```

### Doing the two query inside a single `queryFn`

If inside a single `queryFn` you can chain theses query by awaiting them

```js
 queryFn: async (_args, { getState }, _extraOptions, baseQuery) => {
        const resultFirstQuery = await baseQuery({ url: firstQueryUrl });
        const resultSecondQuery = await baseQuery({ url: secondQueryUrl });
        // Do stuff
      },
```

### Note:

- When you use `getState()` inside a thunk, if the store update this will not trigger your thunk "automatically"
- I do not know if you need the sport to do the second query or to group the result of the two queries together.

Comment: I'd used `extraReducers` in the past. But there were sometimes when I wanted to do something else with the result of an endpoint, or wanted the `extraReducers` behavior only in certain circumstances. I also didn't like the idea of spreading the data around so many places. Instead I colocated these in a `useLoadWhatever` hook that called the `whatever` query hook and then dispatched the data to the `whatever` slice. This is usually for cases where the data needs to be manipulated locally (in the normal redux store).